# Trying to run QT 5 Designer on Ubuntu (Budgie) 18.04 with python 3

Tags: 18.04, budgie, qt5, pyqt5

I have been able to run the QT 5 Designer app from the memnu untill recently. Trying to run from the terminal I get error as below

[image: Screenshot]

It has to do with the libqscintillaplugin.so plugin. The file is available in the plug in directory though.

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled qt5 and pyqt5 and dev tools. Also cleared the apt-get cache and started over

- pip3 install --user pyqt5
- sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
- sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
- sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated